# Model.predict() return different result than model.fit()

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, train-test-split

The model return an accuracy of 36.5% on the fit phase and only 14.5% in the predict phase despite the fact I am considering the same data (val_ds).

What am I doing wrong ?

```
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(200, 200, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.01)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.01)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.01)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')
])

  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

  early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')

  epochs=40
  history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  callbacks=[early_stop],
  epochs=epochs
)
```

val_ds --> <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.SkipDataset'>

train_ds --> <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>

```
cnn1_pred = model.predict(val_ds)
cnn1_pred = cnn1_pred.argmax(axis=-1)

val_label = np.concatenate([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)

count = 0
for n in range(3384):
    if val_label[n] == cnn1_pred[n]:
        count += 1
perf = round(count/3384, 4)
```

EDIT: I noticed that if I run

```
val_label = np.concatenate([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)
print(val_label)
```

I always obtain different results. This shouldn't happen I guess

Answer (score 0):

Did you check with model.evaluate(val_ds) ? try it may be something go wrong with the calculation that you implement to get accuracy `perf`.

Comment: With model.evaluate(val_ds) I get the result I expect (about 35%) but I still don't understand why model.predict return a completely no sense result.
My calculation is not wrong since with the sklearn function `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(val_label, cnn1_pred)` I get the same result (about 14%).

Comment: Regarding your post update, exactly i would told you to check if you get different result of val_lables each time you run it, in this case the sampling is random it is different from lists where is going from the first element to the last one. Check if the load function has arg shuffle = False (check only for the val_ds) and try again.

Comment: I need shuffle=True because data is ordered and I want each class represented in train, val and test sets. Anyway when I create val_ds with the shuffle data should be fixed. But instead it change (e.g. when I call a function like np.concatenate)